# GWT 2.7 Logging Is Not Working

Tags: gwt

I created the sample GWT app in IntelliJ 14 using GWT 2.7 and Java 7. I started Super Dev Mode, but the log statment at the start of onModuleLoad is not printing to the Javascript console. I create a similar example project using GWT 2.5.1 and I was able to get the logging to print using the same logging configuration as described below.

**CodeServer Startup Message**

```
Runing CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.7, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/gwt/gwt5.10e7b474/gwt5.bbec8ec6/run/www, -logLevel, INFO, com.mySampleApplication.MySampleApplication]
```

**MySampleApplicaton.gwt.xml**

```
<module rename-to="MySampleApplication">

<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />

<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

<!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
<entry-point class='com.mySampleApplication.client.MySampleApplication'/>


<!-- Specify the app servlets. -->
<servlet path='/MySampleApplicationService' class='com.mySampleApplication.server.MySampleApplicationServiceImpl'/>

</module>
```

**MySampleApplication.java (*EntryPoint*)**

```
public class MySampleApplication implements EntryPoint {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySampleApplication.class.getName());

  public void onModuleLoad() {
      logger.log(Level.INFO, "Starting module gwt5");
      ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly enabling the `ConsoleLogHandler`? `<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
```

to your module descriptor? This works for me.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sometimes in addition to log messages in the Javascript console, I also see a floating logging panel inside my browser's window. Is there a way to disable the panel? The Javascript console seems fine enough.

Comment: Did not work in my case :( Even with a minimal example.

Comment: @udeleng a bit late, but "<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED"/>" might help you.