# Gwt 2.7 logging dosn't work. Tested with java.util.logging

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, logging

I've started a new GWT **2.7** project, and I am trying to set up logging, but I can't make it work.

I've followed these instructions:

[GWT 2.7 Logging Is Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402833/gwt-2-7-logging-is-not-working)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/Tqu5Zw5H-II

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html

But nothing helped.

Here is my module conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference, 
so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities. -->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN" "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='derp'>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/>

<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.RequestFactory' />

<!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. You can change -->
<!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting -->
<!-- any one of the following lines. -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' /> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark' />
<stylesheet src="/public/css/theme/darkly.min.css" />

<stylesheet src="/public/css/bootstrapOverride.css" />
<stylesheet src="/public/css/gwtOverride.css" />
<stylesheet src="/public/css/Derp.css" />

<!-- Other module inherits -->
<!-- <inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3" /> -->
<inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3NoTheme" />

<stylesheet src="css/font-awesome-4.3.0.min.cache.css" />
<!-- <inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.fullcalendar.FullCalendar" /> -->
<inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.notify.Notify"/>



<!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
<entry-point class='pl.dany.derp.client.Derp' />

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />

<!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
</module>
```

and entry point class:

```
package pl.dany.derp.client;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Derp implements EntryPoint {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Derp.class.getName());


@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    logger.log(Level.ALL, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.FINE, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.FINER, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.FINEST, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.OFF, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    logger.warning("----------------------------------------_>this message should get logged");
    Window.alert("LLLLLLLLLLL 2222");
}
```

I am not getting output in eclipse console:

```
GET /recompile/derp
   Job pl.korbeldaniel.derp.Derp_1_72
      starting job: pl.dany.derp.Derp_1_72
      binding: user.agent=safari
      skipped compile because no input files have changed
      0,022s total -- Compile completed
GET /sourcemaps/derp/ED2FD982D7D3CF133708FC4EC52FB0FB_sourcemap.json
   sent source map for module 'derp' in 31 ms
```

I am getting no output in web browser console.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried GWT.log("hello world!");

Comment: Ok. It worked, but only in chrome console. I didn't get any output in eclipse console (aka server console). I would like to have backend logger working more.

Answer (score 0):

You need add only `<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"`
After adding this property, if server up and running you need to restart it. [I found answer here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/98848)